# Conditionnaly replace "Read more" text WooCommerce products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'd like to replace default "Read more" button text on products conditionnaly.

example: if $product_type = 'simple' && category = 'services' return mystring

So fare, I have :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' , 'custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' );
function custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text() {

    global $product;

    $product_type = $product->product_type;

    switch ( $product_type ) {
        case 'external':
            return __( 'External text', 'woocommerce' );
        break;
        case 'grouped':
            return __( 'Grouped text', 'woocommerce' );
        break;
        case 'simple':
            return __( 'Simple text', 'woocommerce' );
        break;
        case 'variable':
            return __( 'Variable text', 'woocommerce' );
        break;
        default:
            return __( 'Read more', 'woocommerce' );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should check if you're actually replacing `Read more`, you can also remove the `default:` and just make sure you return the original value passed to the filter.

If you specifically want to use `switch` you can use a less commonly used pattern for evaluating statements by setting `switch(true)` and then enclosing the if statement in parenthesis for the `case`

To get/check the categories, there's a couple ways to do this, in my example below i'm using `get_the_terms` to get all the categories, and then mapping all the slugs to an array, so you can use `in_array` (i removed the other case statements for simplicity of the example code):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 10 );

function custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text( $text ) {

    // First make sure that we are only replacing 'Read more' as some situations based on product
    // this can be "Select some options" or "Add to cart"
    $wc_read_more = __( 'Read more', 'woocommerce' );

    if( $text !== $wc_read_more ){
        return $text;
    }

    global $product;

    $product_type = $product->product_type;
    $product_terms = get_the_terms( $product->ID, 'product_cat' );

    // Convert to array of all the slugs
    $pc_slugs = array_map( function($term){ return $term->slug; }, $product_terms );

    switch ( true ) {
        case ( $product_type === 'simple' && in_array( 'services', $pc_slugs ) ):
            return __( 'Simple text', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }

    return $text;
}
```

Another option would be to use `has_term` instead of mapping slugs to an array:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );

function custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text( $text, $that ) {

    // First make sure that we are only replacing 'Read more' as some situations based on product
    // this can be "Select some options" or "Add to cart"
    $wc_read_more = __( 'Read more', 'woocommerce' );

    if( $text !== $wc_read_more ){
        return $text;
    }

    global $product;

    $product_type = $product->product_type;

    switch ( true ) {
        case ( $product_type === 'simple' && has_term( 'services', 'product_cat', $product->ID ) ):
            return __( 'Simple text', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }

    return $text;
}
```

Also want to mention you said `if $product_type = 'simple' && category = 'services'`, in PHP a single `=` is assignment, meaning "set equal to", it's good to get in the habit of always using `==` or `===` (strict) even if just explaining in laments terms

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @sMyles for both well explained examples, very usefull.